# routes.js not working properly when seemingly unused mapStateToProps removed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-native-router-flux

I'm basically cleaning my code right now and found something odd, I found a `mapStateToProps` and `connect` that's not used anywhere within that file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Scene, Router, ActionConst, Stack } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';                  //HERE
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

//import components for scenes
import Splash from '../components/Splash/Splash';
import Login from '../modules/auth/scenes/Login';
import Home from '../modules/home/scenes/Home';
import itemDescription from '../modules/home/scenes/itemDescription';
import About from '../modules/home/scenes/About';
import Setting from '../modules/home/scenes/Setting';
import NavDrawer from '../modules/home/components/NavDrawer';

//Import Store, actions
import store from '../redux/store'
import * as t from '../modules/auth/actionTypes';

export const mapStateToProps = state => ({                      //HERE
    isLoggedIn: state.authReducer.isLoggedIn 
});

class Routes extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            isReady: false,
            isLoggedIn: false,
            userName:""
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        //load token from async and put it in redux's state
        AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then((data) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (data !== null) {
                    this.setState({ isReady: true, isLoggedIn: true });
                    store.dispatch({ type: t.LOGGED_IN, token: data });
                }
                else {
                    this.setState({ isReady: true, isLoggedIn: false })
                    store.dispatch({ type: t.LOGGED_OUT });
                }
            }, 5000)
        });

        //load username from async storage and put it in route's state to be passed to drawer as props
        AsyncStorage.getItem('username').then(name => {
            this.setState({ userName: name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1) });
        }); 
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.state.isReady)
            return <Splash />
        return (
            <Router>
                <Scene key="root" hideNavBar>
                    <Stack key="Auth" initial={!this.state.isLoggedIn}>
                        <Scene key="Login" hideNavBar component={Login} title="Login" />
                    </Stack>
                    <Stack key="Main" initial={this.state.isLoggedIn}>
                        <Scene drawer key="NavDrawer" hideNavBar contentComponent={()=><NavDrawer username={this.state.userName}/>} type={ActionConst.REPLACE} panHandlers={null}>
                            <Scene key="homeTab" title="Home" drawerLockMode={'locked-closed'}>
                                <Scene key="Home" hideNavBar component={Home} title={"Home"} />
                                <Scene key="itemDescription" hideNavBar component={itemDescription} title="Item Description" back />
                            </Scene>
                            <Scene key="aboutTab" title="About" drawerLockMode={'locked-closed'}>
                                <Scene key="About" hideNavBar component={About} title={"About"} />
                            </Scene>
                            <Scene key="settingTab" title="Settings" drawerLockMode={'locked-closed'}>
                                <Scene key="Setting" hideNavBar component={Setting} title={"Setting"} />
                            </Scene>
                        </Scene>
                    </Stack>
                </Scene>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Routes)               //HERE
```

I was pretty sure that these were from my earlier development that I haven't deleted yet, however, when I tried removing those 3 marked lines, and just export default Routes on its own, a few weird things happened:

1. Keyboard doesn't disappear after login
2. Home screen data that depends on the token stored on redux's state suddenly didn't get fetched (fetch was unsuccessful)
3. username doesn't get loaded onto the drawer.

As far as I know `mapStateToProps` is just used to map redux's state to the linked (using `connect`) component's prop so that the component can access them.

It should be a read-only mechanism, because I am setting the redux's state using `store.dispatch` in my `componentDidMount`

What would your guesses be as to why is this happening? Am I understanding something wrong here?

I'm honestly out of ideas on where to look:(

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

UPDATE: I found out that `store.dispatch` in the above snippet doesn't update the token on time when I remove the `mapStateToProps` for some reason, making my Home unable to fetch the data from within its `componentDidMount()` because token was still null. On the next iteration of Home's lifecycle, however, console log shows that token was updated but componentDidMount wasn't called after the update, rather before. question persists, why does `mapStateToProps` matters in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

after some console logging throughout the app, I finally know the reason why it mapStateToProps matters in this case.
So it looks like the scenario was like so:

with mapStateToProps:

routes load token --> dispatch token to store and start loading the home --> home `componentDidMount` triggered but token still null because dispatch is not done --> once dispatch done, **routes is remounted because its subscribing to mapStateToProps that's getting updated with dispatch** --> home reloaded, this time token is there

without:

routes load token --> dispatch token to store and start loading the home --> home `componentDidMount` triggered but token still null because dispatch is not done --> once dispatch done, **routes is NOT remounted because its not subscribing to mapStateToProps that's getting updated with dispatch** --> home is not reloaded

**So it seems my app was working but for a completely wrong reason!!**

So after I removed the `mapStateToProps` to make my app logically sound, it comes down to these 2 sequential lines from the snippet in my question:

```
this.setState({ isReady: true, isLoggedIn: true });
store.dispatch({ type: t.LOGGED_IN, token: data });
```

These 2 lines are **in a race** and the sequence was off to begin with, I should've `dispatched` first then set state to `isReady:true`, that makes more sense than the above snippet because how can I say "hey u can dismiss Splash screen and start loading home" when I haven't even sent the token over to the store!

BUT even after that these 2 lines are still racing because they are both async operations, so now my only problem is how to solve this `race condition`, which is much easier to comprehend! :D